# How to set the whole data property of component to a new object keeping reactivity in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This must have been asked before, but I failed to find such question, so let me apologize in advance if there is one.

In my Vue component (written using vue-property-decorator in a class-based manner) I have a data property which is an object:

```js
const emptyFilters = {
    name: ''
};

export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
    filtersFields = emptyFilters;
    ...
}
```

At some point I'd like to clean the filters. As for now there's only one filter, so I can do this:

```js
        this.filtersFields.name = '';
```

but to make this work with any number of filters, I'd like to do something like this:

```js
        this.filtersFields = emptyFilters;
```

The method above fails which is presumably because I set the property that is an observable to a new object hence the subscription of the model keeps observing the old object instead the new one. As far as I understand, [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) is what I need to use to set the whole `this.filtersFields` to a new object (`emptyFilters`). I tried:

```js
        this.$set(this, 'filtersFields', emptyFilters);
```

but this fails too (an input with `v-model="filtersFields.name"` is not cleared). What am I doing wrong? How to use `Vue.set` correctly? Is it only used only for adding a new property which was not set before? Do I need to use some other method?

PS **As a solution** based on answers below, I decided not to recreate the object from itself, but use a "factory" getter:

```js
// instead of using a const emptyFilters we use a getter because otherwise
// emptyFilters becomes an observable and should be recreated each time anyway
const getEmptyFilters = (): examinationsFilters => ({
    name: ''
});

...

    // (initializing)
    filtersFields: examinationsFilters = getEmptyFilters();

...

        // (in method)
        this.filtersFields = getEmptyFilters();
```

Comment: Yes, `Vue.set` is only used when setting array value by index (instead of doing `arr[2] = value`) or when adding new property to already reactive object. I believe David's solution is correct....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue like this once. It is because (depending on how you are assigning the initial state) you are probably still observing the same object.

Try recreating the object that you want to assign on each assignment.

```js
const emptyFilters = {
    name: ''
};

export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
    methods: {
        setFilters () {
            let filters = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emptyFilters));
            this.$set(this, 'filtersFields', filters);
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: ok, thanks (I've used a slightly different approach, see the PS)

Answer (score 2):

As Jesus Galvan correctly points out, this is very likely caused by your initialization code. Let's say you have the following template:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="filtersFields.firstName" type="text" />
    <input v-model="filtersFields.lastName" type="text" />
    <button @click="onReset">reset</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here's an example implementation that **will not work**:

```js
const EMPTY_FILTERS = { firstName: '', lastName: '' };

export default {
  data() {
    return { filtersFields: EMPTY_FILTERS };
  },
  methods: {
    onReset() {
      this.filtersFields = EMPTY_FILTERS;
    },
  },
};
```

This fails because `this.filtersFields = EMPTY_FILTERS` actually does nothing. Object assignment in JS is done by reference, so `filtersFields` already points to `EMPTY_FILTERS`. Here's an example that does work:

```js
const EMPTY_FILTERS = { firstName: '', lastName: '' };

export default {
  data() {
    return { filtersFields: { ...EMPTY_FILTERS } };
  },
  methods: {
    onReset() {
      this.filtersFields = { ...EMPTY_FILTERS };
    },
  },
};
```

This time we are always assigning a **copy** of `EMPTY_FILTERS`, which will correctly be observed by Vue.

Comment: ok, thanks (I've used a slightly different approach, see the PS)